# react-router-dom 6 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-audit

I want to install `react-router-dom` but when I install it, I see security vulnerability warnings. Running `npm audit` in terminal gave me this:

```
npm audit
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities
```

If you think to say use `npm audit fix --force` I tried it and changed to
`80 vulnerabilities (13 low, 20 moderate, 41 high, 6 critical)` so it didn't work!

How can I fix this 6 high severity vulnerabilities?

Comment: 1. That's nothing to do with react-router (note that's not mentioned _anywhere_ in what you've posted. 2. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

Comment: Also, use extreme caution when applying the `--force` flag as this will bump major versions of dependencies which may introduce breaking changes in dependencies into your app.